# shieldui mvc demo works for me when published, but not other user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, shieldui

I'm testing out ShieldUI graphing in an MVC site using the demo version. (Incidentally, I really like it.) When I publish my site to Azure, my sample graphs look normal to me (apart from "demo version" warning). But when another user views the published site, he doesn't see the graphs. Instead he sees a message that says "thank you for using the trial version of ShieldUI for ASP.NET MVC." Why does it work for me, but not the other user? We're hitting the same site.

Answer (score 0):

The trial message is rendered by the trial version of the Shield.Mvc.UI assembly you are using in the MVC project, but the message should not prevent the chart from showing properly. Make sure you're not getting any javascript errors in the browser console. If the problem does not go away, can you post some code we can look at?